# Trying to send POST Request in Angular on NavigationEnd/ngOnDestroy

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I'm trying to send a list of data objects to a database to save when I leave the navigation. I've tried putting it in ngOnDestroy(), but it seemed like half the times the request made it through to the database before the reference to the list is destroyed, and half the times it sent a null value. This is what I've been trying.

```
this._routerSub = this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      console.log("We have just triggered NavigationEnd! We are now calling .SaveNewJiras()");
      this.sprintListService.SaveNewJiras(this.NewIssues, this.sprintNum).subscribe((result) => {
        this.NewIssues = [];
      }, error => console.log('CALL TO SAVENEWJIRAS() DID NOT WORK!'));
    }
  });
```

and with this in the ngOnDestroy() method.

```
this._routerSub.unsubscribe();
```

What I was encountering was that if I didn't call .unsubscribe(), then it would successfully write to the database. However, navigating back and forth between other pages and that pages would "stack up" NavigationEnd events (which became  a problem because of writing records with primary keys). When I did call .unsubscribe(), it would unsubscribe() the event and the data would never get written to the database. Does anybody have any ideas on how to solve this problem? Thank you so much!

Comment: Not sure if this would work but have you tried moving the `this._routerSub.unsubscribe();` into your `NavigationEnd` handler after you write to the database (in that inner `subscribe` call)?

Comment: Meanwhile, could you elaborate on what "stack up" NavigationEnd events means?  It sounds like the root cause is you are not using rxjs to its fullest power. Would operators like `debounce`, `throttle`, `distinct` help? When multiple events are queued up, you can also consider take the latest and ignore the previous ones.

Comment: You're first solution worked, thank you so much! I do still have a couple of questions though that I want to understand. The reason why i didn't try to do what you suggested was because it looks like you call this._routerSub.unsubscribe() before you finish assigning this._routerSub in the first place! How does that work? Also, when I said "stack up", it seemed like the NavigationEnd events seemed to be getting queued up. I knew this because the log I had in the NavigationEnd handler would write more and more times as I navigated to and from the page. Is there an explanation for this? Thanks!